# viewController is presented before the segue has been passed

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a set of buttons and I want to send their title to the next page using segue . Here is what I have done :

```
// in my first page i have : 
 @IBAction func btn_language_action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let chosen_language = sender.currentTitle!
        print(chosen_language)
        let game_level = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "game_level") as! game_level_viewController
        self.present(game_level, animated: false, completion: nil)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GL", sender: chosen_language)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let game_level_viewController = segue.destination as! game_level_viewController
        game_level_viewController.language = sender as? String

    }
```

and in the second view I have :

```
  @IBOutlet weak var lang: UILabel!
    var language : String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       setUI()
    }

    func setUI (){

        lang.text = language
        print(language )

    }
```

I can pass the information successfully however , however the view has already been loaded before I receive what was sent . Any idea how can I fix this ? 
In the console I have :

```
language ==>  nil
language ==>  Optional("Persian")
```

[image]

Comment: you should either present the vc or segue to it. don't do both. get rid of the present line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is due to this line

```
self.present(game_level, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

why you are presenting this controller even if you have given segue to the controller

Remove this two lines and all will work good

```
 let game_level = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "game_level") as! game_level_viewController
        self.present(game_level, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written two lines which both are used for transition between view controllers, So when you use segue don't present viewcontroller simultaneously.
Problem in your code is in this line, try to remove below code.

```
self.present(game_level, animated: false, completion: nil)
```